# Ngix configuration for two odoo instances

Tags: nginx, server, configuration, odoo

I want to run multiple subdomains on same server each connected to a different odoo instance and all instances are running on different ports. However, I can't get one of the subdomains working, here are my configuration files, I know only one of them is the subdomain and other one is proper domain, but the you can get the idea:

**example1.com.conf**

```
# Odoo servers
upstream odoo {
 server 127.0.0.1:8030;
}

upstream odoochat {
 server 127.0.0.1:8072;
}

# HTTP -> HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example1.com example1.com;

    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
    return 301 https://example1.com$request_uri;
}

# WWW -> NON WWW
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example1.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/chain.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    return 301 https://example1.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example1.com;

    proxy_read_timeout 720s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
    proxy_send_timeout 720s;

    # Proxy headers
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    # SSL parameters
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/privkey.pem
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    # log files
    access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

    # Handle longpoll requests
    location /longpolling {
        proxy_pass http://odoochat;
    }

    # Handle / requests
    location / {
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_pass http://odoo;
    }

    # Cache static files
    location ~* /web/static/ {
        proxy_cache_valid 200 90m;
        proxy_buffering on;
        expires 864000;
        proxy_pass http://odoo;
    }

    # Gzip
    gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
    gzip on;
}
```

**example2.mydomain.com**

```
# Odoo servers
upstream example2 {
 server 127.0.0.1:8015;
}

upstream example2-chat {
 server 127.0.0.1:8072;
}

# HTTP -> HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example2.mydomain.com example2.mydomain.com;

    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
    return 301 https://example2.mydomain.com$request_uri;
}

# WWW -> NON WWW
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example2.mydomain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.mydomain.com/chain.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    return 301 https://example2.mydomain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example2.mydomain.com;

    proxy_read_timeout 720s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
    proxy_send_timeout 720s;

    # Proxy headers
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    # SSL parameters
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

   # log files
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example2.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example2.error.log;

    # Handle longpoll requests
    location /longpolling {
        proxy_pass http://example2-chat;
    }

    # Handle / requests
    location / {
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_pass http://example2;
    }

    # Cache static files
    location ~* /web/static/ {
        proxy_cache_valid 200 90m;
        proxy_buffering on;
        expires 864000;
        proxy_pass http://example2;
    }

    # Gzip
    gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
    gzip on;

}
```

`example1.com` is working just fine, however, whenever I click on anything on `example2.mydomain.com` it will redirect me to the name to upstream so for example:

- There is a button that will take me to `example2.mydomain.com/web`
- Upon clicking it will take me to `example2/web` instead
- If I manually input `example2.mydomain.com/web` in URL it will work just fine

I have gone through documentations, articles etc but can't figure out what I am missing in the configuration? Id it odoo thing because default `odoo & odoochat` upstreams are working but not the custom one that I have defined.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two configs I use for a customer for his production and staging environments.

It works fine.

However, don't forget to change things like having both Odoo running, changing the odoo.conf (and odoo2.conf) files with their respective longpolling and http ports, having web.base.url set in your Odoo's system parameters, etc.

In your example above, I see both configurations use the same longpolling port, not sure it's already a good idea :)

If you need more details, don't hesitate asking me.

(All this on Ubuntu 20.04)

Production:

```
#odoo server
 upstream odoo {
  server 127.0.0.1:8069;
 }
 upstream odoochat{
  server 127.0.0.1:8092;
 }
 server {
     server_name example.com;
  proxy_read_timeout 720s;
  proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
  proxy_send_timeout 720s;
  # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  # log
  access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;
  # Redirect longpoll requests to odoo longpolling port
  location /longpolling {
  proxy_pass http://odoochat;
  }
  # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
  location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://odoo;
  }
  # common gzip
  gzip_types text/css text/scss text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
  gzip on;



    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

}


 server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


     server_name example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404;


}
```

Staging :

```
#odoo server
 upstream odoostaging {
  server 127.0.0.1:8079;
 }
 upstream odoochatstaging {
  server 127.0.0.1:8082;
 }
 server {
     server_name staging.example.com;
  proxy_read_timeout 720s;
  proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
  proxy_send_timeout 720s;
  # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  # log
  access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;
  # Redirect longpoll requests to odoo longpolling port
  location /longpolling {
  proxy_pass http://odoochatstaging;
  }
  # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
  location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://odoostaging;
  }
  # common gzip
  gzip_types text/css text/scss text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
  gzip on;



    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

}


 server {
    if ($host = staging.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


     server_name staging.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404;


}
```

In case you need them, here are the Odoo configurations :

/etc/odoo/odoo.conf

```
[options]
addons_path = /home/ubuntu/prod/odoo/addons,/home/ubuntu/prod/enterprise,/home/ubuntu/prod/custom
admin_passwd = mySuperAdminPassword
csv_internal_sep = ,
data_dir = /var/lib/odoo/.local/share/Odoo
db_host = localhost
db_maxconn = 64
db_name = prodDb
db_password = prodDbPassword
db_port = False
db_sslmode = prefer
db_template = template0
db_user = myDbUser
dbfilter = ^prodDb$
demo = {}
email_from = False
geoip_database = /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb
http_enable = True
http_interface = 
http_port = 8069
import_partial = 
limit_memory_hard = 2684354560
limit_memory_soft = 2147483648
limit_request = 8192
limit_time_cpu = 300
limit_time_real = 900
limit_time_real_cron = -1
list_db = True
log_db = True
log_db_level = warning
log_handler = :INFO
log_level = info
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
longpolling_port = 8092
max_cron_threads = 1
osv_memory_age_limit = False
osv_memory_count_limit = False
pg_path = 
pidfile = 
proxy_mode = True
reportgz = False
screencasts = 
screenshots = /tmp/odoo_tests
server_wide_modules = base,web
smtp_password = False
smtp_port = 25
smtp_server = localhost
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_user = False
syslog = False
test_enable = False
test_file = 
test_tags = None
transient_age_limit = 1.0
translate_modules = [all]
unaccent = False
upgrade_path = 
without_demo = True
workers = 5
```

/etc/odoo/odoo-staging.conf

```
[options]
addons_path = /home/ubuntu/staging/odoo/addons,/home/ubuntu/staging/enterprise,/home/ubuntu/staging/custom
admin_passwd = myAdminPassword
csv_internal_sep = ,
data_dir = /var/lib/odoo/.local/share/Odoo
db_host = localhost
db_maxconn = 64
db_name = False
db_password = myDbPassword
db_port = False
db_sslmode = prefer
db_template = template0
db_user = myDbUser
dbfilter =
demo = {}
email_from = False
geoip_database = /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb
http_enable = True
http_interface = 
http_port = 8079
import_partial = 
limit_memory_hard = 2684354560
limit_memory_soft = 2147483648
limit_request = 8192
limit_time_cpu = 300
limit_time_real = 900
limit_time_real_cron = -1
list_db = True
log_db = True
log_db_level = warning
log_handler = :INFO
log_level = info
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
longpolling_port = 8082
max_cron_threads = 1
osv_memory_age_limit = False
osv_memory_count_limit = False
pg_path = 
pidfile = 
proxy_mode = True
reportgz = False
screencasts = 
screenshots = /tmp/odoo_tests
server_wide_modules = base,web
smtp_password = False
smtp_port = 25
smtp_server = localhost
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_user = False
syslog = False
test_enable = False
test_file = 
test_tags = None
transient_age_limit = 1.0
translate_modules = [all]
unaccent = False
upgrade_path = 
without_demo = True
workers = 3
```

Comment: Hey, your example includes two different nginx files, right? with the name staging and production

Comment: Yes I'm mostly working with different Ports for longpolling and http + different domains :)